# Python 3.8 : How to split information nicely

Tags: python, split, findall

I have a log file which contains these information :

```
- TEST B1

B1_D<4.9b(8.9,9.25)B

B1_D=16.9b(15.9,17.25)B

H32_DOT_FAT<4.9H(5.9,7.25)H

 H32_DOT_FBAT<4.9H(5.9,7.25)H

R31=1.5K(1.45K,1.54K)R 

R33=3.8K(3.62K,4.17K)R
```

I want to parse this file like as below :

**Legend**

```
SCN : first line
STEP : first part of split for "_" seperator
CHILD : the rest of split  for "_" seperator
MESURE_CHILD : the rest of split for "=" separator or " < "
```

**Output Expected :**

```
SCN = TEST B1 
STEP = B1
CHILD = D
MESURE_CHILD : 4.9b(8.9,9.25)B
CHILD : D
MESURE_CHILD : 16.9b(15.9,17.25)B
STEP = H32
CHILD = DOT_FAT
MESURE_CHILD : 4.9H(5.9,7.25)H
CHILD : DOT_FBAT
MESURE_CHILD : 4.9H(5.9,7.25)H
STEP = R31
CHILD : R31
MESURE_CHILD : 1.5K(1.45K,1.54K)R
STEP = R33
CHILD : R33
MESURE_CHILD : 3.8K(3.62K,4.17K)R
```

I use python 3.8 to coding. You find as below method that i used but i don't find the solution nicely

```
def createTreeStandardBloc(self, data_bloc):

    index_bloc = 1
    data = data_bloc[ 0 ]
    if ( "=" in data [ index_bloc ] or "<" in data [ index_bloc ] ) :
        prefix = re.split(r'(<|=)\s*', data [ index_bloc ] )[ 0 ]
        if ( "_" in prefix ):
            step_name = re.split( "_" , prefix )[ 0 ]
        else:
            step_name = prefix

    print("STEP : "+step_name)
    for index_bloc in range( 2 , len( data ) ) :
        if ( "=" in data [ index_bloc ] or "<" in data [ index_bloc ] ) :
            prefix_pdm = re.split(r'(<|=)\s*', data [ index_bloc ] )[ 0 ]
            if ( "_" in prefix_pdm ):
                step_name_temp = re.split( "_" , prefix_pdm ) [ 0 ]
                pdm            = re.split( "_" , prefix_pdm ) [ 1 ]
            else:
                step_name_temp = prefix_pdm
                pdm            = prefix_pdm                   

        if ( step_name_temp != step_name ):
            step_name = step_name_temp
            print("STEP : "+step_name)
            print("CHILD : "+pdm)

        else :
            print("CHILD : "+pdm)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression for getting the parts from the lines:

```
import re
last_s = None
for i, line in enumerate(data.splitlines()):
    if i == 0:
        print("SCN:", line.strip("- "))
    elif line.strip():
        s, c, mc = re.match("^\s*([^_]+)(_\w+)?[<>=](.*)\s*$", line).groups()
        if s != last_s:
            print("STEP", s)
        print("CHILD", c or s)
        print("MEASURE_CHILD", mc)
        last_s = s
```

Let's break this down a bit:

- `^\s*` -- start of line, possibly whitespace
- `([^_]+)` -- some non-underscore chars (1st group)
- `(_\w+)?` -- underscore, then more characters (2nd group)
- `[<>=](.*)` -- comparison, more stuff (3rd group)
- `\s*$` -- optional whitespace, then end of line

Comment: Thank's for your answer but the data is not a list, it's a line of the list because i  get this error when i run your code AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'splitlines'

Comment: @TheRight Well, if it's already a list of lines (or a file handle or whatever) just drop the `splitlines` and iterate the lines directly: `for i, line in enumerate(data):`

Comment: Yes it's work now but there is a small problem that normaly the step H32 and the step B1 have two child and not repeat step tag. For example : -STEP = B1 
 - CHILD = D
 - MESURE_CHILD : 4.9b(8.9,9.25)B
 - CHILD : D
 - MESURE_CHILD : 16.9b(15.9,17.25)B

Comment: Check the expected output please for more details

Comment: @TheRight If those lines are next to each other, you can just keep track of the previous `s` value in another variable and only print the `STEP` line if it changed.

Comment: can you edit your answer please that i can understand what you explain ?.

Comment: It's possible to add variable which contain the detected operator ?.

Comment: @TheRight Sure, just surround that part with another group `([<>=])` and add anotehr variable when unpacking the `groups()`